# Subtle difference in two (almost) similar structures

Tags: c++, c, struct, architecture

So, there are two 'almost' similar structure in 'C' code

**1st:**

```
struct P1 {
    int i;
    char c;
    char d;
    int e;
};
printf("3. size of struct is, %d\n", sizeof(P1));
```

Gives a console Output: `3. size of struct is, 12`

**2nd:**

```
struct P2 {
    int i;
    char c;
    int e;
    char d;
};
printf("4. size of struct is, %d\n", sizeof(P2));
```

Gives the console output: `4. size of struct is, 16`

Can anyone explain the discrepancy? (Even though both the struct have 2 int and two char) 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: How is the question related to C++? (ok, the answer happens to be the same for both languages in this case)

Comment: Pls see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1841863/size-of-a-structure-in-c

Comment: I would appreciate if you could see my two structures and answer the discrepancy as asked in the question, I think I understand the padding and memory alignment concept a bit, if I can get an answer for my particular question, I may get better understanding @ F. Ju

Comment: @user3204053 in the second one you have int (4byte) + char(1byte + 3 padding) + int(4byte) + char(1byte+ 3 padding) which equals 16. In the first you have int(4byte) + 2x (char 2byte + 2 padding) + int (4 byte) which equals 12.

Comment: Thius is homework isn't it?  Yout don't want any hints or links, you WANT YOUR QUESTION ANSWERED IN FULL HERE for copypasta.