# Getting wrong output while executing sizeof(char)

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

My question is sizeof(char) is 1 byte but while executing below code why I am getting wrong output. Kindly help me. Thank you

```
typedef struct {

   int x;      
   int y;

   char a;

}Point2D;

main() {
   Point2D *myPoint=malloc(sizeof(Point2D));
   NSLog(@"sizeof(Point2D): %zu", sizeof(Point2D));
}
```

Output: sizeof(Point2D) : 12 //But it should return 9 [int + int + char / 4 + 4 + 1]

Note: While running char individually , I am getting correct output

Example:

```
typedef struct {

   char a;

   char b;

}Point2D;

main() {

   Point2D *myPoint=malloc(sizeof(Point2D));

   NSLog(@"sizeof(Point2D): %zu", sizeof(char));

}
```

output: sizeof(char) : 2

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/119123/why-isnt-sizeof-for-a-struct-equal-to-the-sum-of-sizeof-of-each-member

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1841863/size-of-struct-in-c

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not getting "wrong" output, when an (Objective-)C compiler lays out a `struct` it is allowed to use internal padding so that the fields start at the best memory alignment for their type.

If you need the size of a `struct` to be exactly the sum of its field sizes you can use `__attribute__((__packed__))`. E.g:

```
typedef struct
{
   int x;
   int y;
   char a;
} __attribute__((__packed__)) Point2D;
```

has a size of `9`. However access to the fields *may* be slower due to the CPU having to deal with values not having optimal storage alignment.