# Is there a problem with reading multiple elements from a pointer with fread?

Tags: arrays, file, pointers, segmentation-fault, fread

Here is the structure:

```
typedef struct {
    int nr_operations;
    int *operations_idxs;
} sensor;
```

I try to read from a FILE elements in operations_idxs.

I get segmentation fault using this code:

```
S[i].operations_idxs=(int*)malloc(S[i].nr_operations*sizeof(int));
fread(&S[i].operations_idxs, sizeof(int), S[i].operations_idxs, f);
```

But works well with this code, reading right data:

```
S[i].operations_idxs=(int*)malloc(S[i].nr_operations*sizeof(int));
for( j=0; j<S[i].nr_operations; j++) {
    fread(&S[i].operations_idxs[j], sizeof(int), 1, f);
}
```

Comment: Please use triple back-quotes before, and after, your code.

Comment: I have little knowledge about C, but this might be the problem [size of struct in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1841863/size-of-struct-in-c)

Answer (score 0):

Well, i didn't see that i used the address of the pointer `S[i].operations_idxs` as the first argument.

So i had to use this to work:

```
 S[i].operations_idxs=(int*)malloc(S[i].nr_operations*sizeof(int));
 fread(S[i].operations_idxs, sizeof(int), S[i].operations_idxs, f);
```