# Receiving C type Struct from a ESP8266 with a Raspberry Pi 4 not working with the RF24 library (ESP8266 to ESP32 works fine)

Tags: python, c++, arduino, raspberry-pi, esp32

Hi this is my first RPi project and Im trying to receive a c type struct (see code) that is being send by a ESP8266 using the RF24 library.

Everything is working fine if I use a ESP32 with the following code:

```cpp
#include <Arduino.h>
#include <SPI.h>
#include <RF24.h>

//PMX Data Structure
struct nrfDataStruct{
  uint8_t change;
  float pm10;
  float sumBins;
  float temp;
  float altitude;
  float hum;
  float xtra;
}payload;

//RF24
RF24 radio(3, 10); //CE, CSN

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  while(!radio.begin()) {
    noRFscreen();
  }
  radio.openReadingPipe(1, 1); //Tansmitter uses 0 as default pipe so we use 1 as receiver (0-5)
  radio.setChannel(108); //PMX channel
  radio.setDataRate(RF24_250KBPS); //PMX uses 250kbps (this is good for longer range)
  radio.setAutoAck(false);  //size is fixed so we don't need acknoledgement
  radio.setPALevel(RF24_PA_MAX);
  radio.startListening();
}

void loop() {
  if (radio.available()) {
    radio.read(&payload, sizeof(payload));
  }
  delay(10);
}
```

Now I want to do exactly the same with an Raspberry Pi 4 (64bit OS) so I compiled and installed the same library as shown here: https://github.com/nRF24/RF24/blob/master/docs/using_cmake.md

But it doesn't matter if I use the C++ library or the Python wrapper library the data doesnt match at all. I hope someone can help me with this.

RPi4 C++ Code and Output:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <time.h>
#include <RF24/RF24.h>

#define CSN_PIN 0
#ifdef MRAA
    #define CE_PIN 15
#else
    #define CE_PIN 22
#endif

RF24 radio(CE_PIN, CSN_PIN);

//PMX Data Structure
struct nrfDataStruct{
  uint8_t change;
  float pm10;
  float sumBins;
  float temp;
  float altitude;
  float hum;
  float xtra;
}payload;

struct timespec startTimer, endTimer;
uint32_t getMicros();
uint32_t delayTime = 10000;
uint32_t timerElapsed = 0;

int main(){
    // perform hardware check
    if (!radio.begin()){
        std::cout << "radio hardware is not responding!!!\n";
        return 1;
    }
    clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC_RAW, &startTimer);
    radio.openReadingPipe(1, 1);
    radio.setChannel(108);
    radio.setDataRate(RF24_250KBPS);
    radio.setAutoAck(false);
    radio.setPALevel(RF24_PA_MAX);
    radio.startListening();

    while(true) {
        if ((timerElapsed = getMicros()) >= delayTime) {
            if (radio.available()) {
                radio.read(&payload, sizeof(payload));
                std::cout << "PMX Data: " << payload.change << " " << payload.pm10 << " " << payload.sumBins << " " << payload.temp << " " << payload.altitude << " " << payload.hum << " " << payload.xtra << "\n";
            }
            clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC_RAW, &startTimer);
        }
    }
    
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

uint32_t getMicros(){
    clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC_RAW, &endTimer);
    uint32_t seconds = endTimer.tv_sec - startTimer.tv_sec;
    uint32_t useconds = endTimer.tv_nsec - startTimer.tv_nsec / 1000;
    return ((seconds)*1000 + useconds) + 0.5;
}
```

Output:

```bash
...
PMX Data: 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
PMX Data: 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
PMX Data: 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
...
```

pyRF24 library:

```py
import struct
from pyrf24 import RF24, RF24_CRC_DISABLED, RF24_PA_MAX, RF24_250KBPS

radio = RF24(22, 0)

if not radio.begin():
    raise OSError("nRF24L01 hardware isn't responding")

radio.set_pa_level(RF24_PA_MAX)

radio.open_rx_pipe(1, 1)
radio.setChannel(108)
radio.setDataRate(RF24_250KBPS)
radio.setAutoAck(False)

# calc payload size
radio.payload_size = struct.calcsize("<Bffffff")
radio.print_details()

while True:
    radio.listen = True
    has_payload, pipe_number = radio.available_pipe()
    if has_payload:
        length = radio.payload_size
        received = radio.read(length)
        nrfDataStruct = struct.unpack("<Bffffff", received)
        print(nrfDataStruct)
```

Output:

```bash
================ SPI Configuration ================
CSN Pin         = /dev/spidev0.0
CE Pin          = Custom GPIO22
SPI Speedz      = 10 Mhz
================ NRF Configuration ================
STATUS          = 0x0e RX_DR=0 TX_DS=0 MAX_RT=0 RX_P_NO=7 TX_FULL=0
RX_ADDR_P0-1    = 0xe7e7e7e7e7 0x0000000001
RX_ADDR_P2-5    = 0xc3 0xc4 0xc5 0xc6
TX_ADDR         = 0xe7e7e7e7e7
RX_PW_P0-6      = 0x19 0x19 0x19 0x19 0x19 0x19
EN_AA           = 0x00
EN_RXADDR       = 0x03
RF_CH           = 0x6c
RF_SETUP        = 0x27
CONFIG          = 0x0e
DYNPD/FEATURE   = 0x00 0x00
Data Rate       = 250 KBPS
Model           = nRF24L01+
CRC Length      = 16 bits
PA Power        = PA_MAX
ARC             = 0
```

Nothing else

Pin Connections on the RPi4:
Using pin 15(GPIO22) for CE, pin 24(GPIO8 commonly labeled as CE0) for CS

Comment: I'm not familiar with those platforms, but since your code invokes some UB which is impacted by different alignment of struct fields (here of type `float`) for specific platform. This is important since you done naive implementation of reading by `radio.read(&payload, sizeof(payload));`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1841871/1387438 note `float` on ARM must be aligned otherwise program crashes.

Comment: @MarekR Ive printed the sizeof the struct on both platforms and on both it says the struct is 28 bytes. So its the same. And the endianess is on both little endian so it should work!?