# Struct de reference using null

Tags: c

```
int main()
{
    typedef struct name
    {
        long a;
        int b;
        long c;
    } r;
    r re = { 3, 7, 5 };

    printf("%d", ((unsigned int)&(( struct name *)0)->b));

    printf("%d", ((int)&((struct name *)0)->a));

    while(1);
}
```

I find that the program gives the offset of the member of the structure. So, probably similar to `offsetof()`. But, This is the first time i am seeing the typecast with `'0'`. What does that mean ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is apparent NULL pointer dereference in C actually pointer arithmetic?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4532797/is-apparent-null-pointer-dereference-in-c-actually-pointer-arithmetic)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this is an attempt to implement `offsetof`. They're putting the beginning of the struct pointer at 0, such that the addres of `b` will indicate its offset.

However, this is not good code. First, dereferencing a null pointer (as is done with `->b`) is undefined behavior, even if nothing is done with that value other than taking a pointer to it. Secondly (and this is where it gets weird), the null pointer -- despite being written `0` -- is not guaranteed to actually be at location 0 in memory, so the result casted to an int is not necessarily the offset of the member.

Some standard library implementations do implement `offsetof` this way, if they are meant to work with compilers which are willing to deal with those standard-violating problems. However, you should not rely on this in your own code. That's what `offsetof` is for.