# What is this macro exactly doing?

Tags: c, pointers, structure, offset

```
#define offsetof(type, member)  ((size_t)(&((type *)0)->member))
```

I am not understanding `(&((type *)0)->member)` what is this exactly telling me.....

here type may be a structure or something else??...

More specifically what is that 0 telling me here??

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why does this C code work?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/713963/why-does-this-c-code-work)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I break it down like this:

1. `(type *)0` - casting `0` to a pointer to type "`type`". i.e. imagine for a minute that there's an object of type "`type`" at memory address 0.
2. `->member` - look into the object for the field called `member`.
3. `&` - take the address of that.

You could also write it like this:

```
((size_t)((&((type *)x)->member) - x))
```

But we're cheating and using `0` so that there's no offset to take off at the end.

Comment: Ya, I got it that it is giving me the offset of structure, but I am not getting why do we give the type* over here.... it should work for (&((type)0)->member)... am I missing something. ???

Comment: The `- x` bit shouldn't be in parentheses before the `size_t` cast, or else it will subtract `x` from a `type *` - which is probably not the same as subtracting `x` from a number.

Comment: Chris - I put in more parentheses to cope with that and to make it simpler - look closer :-).

Comment: If I use Type*, it should give a seg fault right...???.. SO, I thought ((type)0) should work...

Answer (score 6):

This is to determine the offset of a struct field.  It works by using 0 as the address of the struct, then asking for the address of the field:

```
(type *)0
```

is 0 as a pointer to `type`

```
&((type *)0)->member
```

is the address of that hypothetical struct's `member` member.  If the address of the struct is 0, then the address of the member is the same as the offset from the beginning of the struct.

```
((size_t)(&((type *)0)->member))
```

is that address cast to a `size_t` to be the proper type for an offset.

Comment: Ya, I got it that it is giving me the offset of structure, but I am not getting why do we give the type* over here.... it should work for (&((type)0)->member)... am I missing something. ???

Comment: Yes. `(type)0` is not lvalue, and haven't an address. You need the object that its address (no value!) is 0. BTW, I'm pretty sure that the whole thing is UB.

Comment: @asaelr - It is - oddly, the standard optimizes `&*(type *)0` and `&((type *)0)[x]` but not `&((type *)0)->member` - but it "usually" works. On platforms where it doesn't, using `(type *)1024` will almost always work - it should be aligned for almost any type. Just remember to subtract that number from the end result at the end of the macro.

Comment: If I use Type*, it should give a seg fault right...???.. SO, I thought ((type)0) should work

Comment: @Invictus No, because you never access the data at that address: you're simply using it as a reference.  You don't need to know what's _at_ the address (of zero) to find the offset.  (But if you looked, then yes, you'd seg fault (depending on your system)).

Answer (score 3):

The macro is casting an address (0) to a declared type ("type") then accessing a field ("member") and getting the address.  The result is that the address of the field, offset from address 0, gives the offset form the beginning of the type (structure/union) to the field.

Comment: Ya, I got it that it is giving me the offset of structure, but I am not getting why do we give the type* over here.... it should work for (&((type)0)->member)... am I missing something. ???

Comment: Where is your constant stored? Change the zero to an arbitrary number - '123' say, either way, you'd be asking the compiler to give you the address of a constant plus the offset of a member, not the address of an _address_ plus the offset of a member, which is why you cast as a pointer.

Comment: Can you please explain me what is a constant here and what is a member here.... I am getting a bit confused...