# why doesn't this segfault?

Tags: c++, c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why does this C code work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/713963/why-does-this-c-code-work)

Why doesn't this code for finding the offset of a field in a struct give segfault ?

```
#define offset(structName,fieldName) (&((structName *)0)->fieldName)
```

Comment: Funny, usually people ask why their code _does_ give segfault...

Comment: It might; technically, it's undefined behavior. But most compilers will optimize this to a constant number, so in those, this can be used as the implementation of offsetof(). In general, offsetof() implementation is left up to the compiler; gcc does indeed use __builtin_offsetof().

Comment: Wikipedia page on offsetof gives some clues: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Offsetof

Comment: And the library delivered with the compiler can do things like this, because the library knows exactly what the compiler will do with it.  As a programmer, you shouldn't (unless you don't care about portability and the compiler explicitly guarantees it).

Comment: Undefined behavior doesn't mean "this will crash". It means the behavior is undefined.

Answer (score 3):

Because it is not accessing any data. It's just computing an address.
Try doing either of these operations:

```
foo = *offset(MyStruct, MyField);
*offset(MyStruct, MyField) = 1234;
```

And you'll see a beautiful SEGFAULT :-)