# structure offset macro

Tags: c, pointers, struct, offset

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why does this C code work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/713963/why-does-this-c-code-work)

I do see a macro defined to compute the structure offset as follows

`#define offsetof(st, m) ((size_t)(&((st *)0)->m))`

But I don't get on how this definition works. It looks like a member of structure is accessed via a `NULL` pointer. Can any one please elaborate how this expression works?

Comment: The pointer isn't actually dereferenced.

Answer (score 1):

This expression is optimized in compile-time, resulting into a compile-time offset value in your program.

Compiler sees a constant pointer (0), sees a constant offset from it and just applies [constant folding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constant_folding), producing the address `0 + offset` (== offset), which is what we need.

It's interesting whether this works without any optimizations or some basic constant folding is done always.

P.S. More precisely this optimization is called `Scalar Replacement of Aggregates`, as was pointed out by Lei Mou below.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out that this is due to compiler optimization. However, from what I tried with clang and opt, the pass "Scalar Replacement of Aggregates" actually transform this macro into a constant.

Comment: @LeiMou Yes, it's more precise name for this optimization. I've just applied my knowledge from 'Compilers' at Coursera to give a name to this behavior :)

Answer (score 1):

1) First a null pointer to a structure of type 'st' is created: (st *)0

2) Next the member of of this structure is taken: ->m

3) Next the address of the member is taken: &(...)

4) Finally the address of the member is cast to a size-t type: (size_t)(...)

The work happens at step 3, as the pointer is null (i.e. address == 0) then the address off the member simply contains the members position within the structure.