# Processing member of an array of structs in a function

Tags: c, arrays, structure, member

Let's say I have

```
struct my_type_t {
    int x;
    int y;
    int z;
};

struct my_array_t {
    struct my_type_t test;
    int otherstuff;
};

int main(void) {
    struct my_array_t arrayofstructs[200];
    somefunction(arrayofstructs);

    return 0;
}

void somefunction(struct my_array_t *arrayofstructs, somevariable) {
    for (int i; i < 200; i++) {
        //Do stuff to 
        arrayofstructs->test[i].somevariable;
    }
}
```

How can I pass in somevariable to tell the function to process that member (x, y, or z) of the array of structs?

Thanks!

Comment: Not what you're asking, but it should be `arrayofstructs[i].test.somevariable`.

Answer (score 1):

**Fact One:**  You should pass, `arrayofstructs` and not `&arraystructs`.

A way to deal with your problem would be like this:

```
void someFn(data_type *var , int somevar) {
  ...
  ...
  ...
  switch(somevar) {

  case <some_value>:
  some_task;
  break;

  ...
  ...
  ...
  } //End switch

  }
```

i.e., you pass an identifier related to  each of the member and use selective structure to perform certain tasks according to the input identifier.

For a simple example, `somevar` can be integer, and you must know what the value in the integer corresponds to.

**EDIT**

Or you can do the following

```
struct mystr{
  int mem[3];
}

void someFn(struct mystr a, int somevar){ 

  //now access those with a[i].mem[somevar]
}
```

That helps clearing the redundancy :)

Comment: Correct, arrayofstructs is the address of arrayofstructs[];  I was hoping there was an easier way without using switch case.

Comment: @user2272403 :  arrayofstructs is address of arrayofstructs[0] :)

Comment: Yes yes, 0 it is.  some_task is pretty big so I was trying to eliminate redundant code.

Comment: I'm sorry we cannot do that, I think redundant code cannot be eliminated in your case

Comment: Interesting... I thought about using address offset, but this looks cleaner than when I tried to implement it.  I'll check it out.

Answer (score 1):

The other answers using switch case are probably cleaner but if some hackiness is okay you can use something like this:

```
#define GET_STRUCT_OFFSET(st, m) ((size_t) ( (char *)&((st *)(0))->m - (char *)0 ))
```

(see [Why does this implementation of offsetof() work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/713963/why-does-this-c-code-work))

To access a member of the struct you would do something like:

```
int main(void) {
    struct my_array_t arrayofstructs[200];
    somefunction(arrayofstructs, GET_STRUCT_OFFSET(struct my_type_t, x));

   return 0;
}

void somefunction(struct my_array_t *arrayofstructs, int offset)
{
    for (int i; i < 200; i++) {
        //Do stuff to 
        (((void*)&arrayofstructs[i].test) + offset);
    }
}
```

Again pretty hacky but it does infact work heres a simple test: http://ideone.com/zwvTY1

Edit:

In `<stddef.h>` there is an `offsetof` macro which accomplishes the same thing code using that: http://ideone.com/9aDo2c

Comment: I thought about using address offset, but this code needs to be portable between machines of differing structure alignments and I thought using this technique would cause problems.

Comment: @user2272403 See edit I just realized there is a standard version.

Comment: I like this one too.  It does require one extra addition per iteration of the loop, though,  but everything comes with a price.

Comment: Well to be fair the macro will take a bit extra as would a switch case. Though I doubt either would be a bottle neck compared to whatever the "Do stuff" is.

Answer (score 0):

```
enum FieldTypes
{
   FIELD_X,
   FIELD_Y,
   FIELD_Z
};

int main(void)
{
    struct my_array_t arrayofstructs[200];
    somefunction(arrayofstructs,FIELD_X);

    return 0;
}

void somefunction(struct my_array_t *arrayofstructs, FieldTypes somevariable) 
{
    switch( somevariable )
    {
        case FIELD_X:

           for (int i; i < 200; i++) 
           {
               //Do stuff to arrayofstructs->test[i].x; 
           }
           break;

        case FIELD_Y:

           for (int i; i < 200; i++) 
           {
               //Do stuff to arrayofstructs->test[i].y; 
           }
           break;

        case FIELD_Z:

           for (int i; i < 200; i++) 
           {
               //Do stuff to arrayofstructs->test[i].z;
           }
           break;
    }
}
```

If the intent is to always do the same operation, but just do it on a different element of the structure based on the passed value, then you can do that like this...

```
void somefunction(struct my_array_t *arrayofstructs, FieldTypes somevariable) 
{
    for (int i; i < 200; i++) 
    {
        int* workingValue;

        switch( somevariable )
        {
            case FIELD_X: workingValue = &arrayofstructs->test[i].x;  break;
            case FIELD_Y: workingValue = &arrayofstructs->test[i].y;  break;
            case FIELD_Z: workingValue = &arrayofstructs->test[i].z;  break;
        }

        // do stuff to *workingValue -- no redundant code here
    }
}
```

Comment: I was hoping to eliminate redundant code, but I do like the enumerated FieldTypes and case switch idea.

Answer (score 0):

Just use some distinct values to allow your function to distinguish between them. You could use an `enum`, some `#define`s or maybe a `char`, like this:

```
void somefunction(struct my_array_t *arrayofstructs, char whichVar) {
    for (int i; i < 200; i++) {
        //Do stuff to 
        switch(whichVar){
            case 'x': arrayofstructs->test[i].x; break;
            case 'y': arrayofstructs->test[i].y; break;
            case 'z': arrayofstructs->test[i].z; break;
        }
    }
}
```

Note that using `#define`s or `enum`s is generally considered better practice as you can give your values meaningful names. The `char` usage here is just an example.

See also [What is a magic number, and why is it bad?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47882/what-is-a-magic-number-and-why-is-it-bad)