# What does `((t*)0)->f)` do in C code?

Tags: c, linux, macros, sizeof

I saw the following weird type of macro in C (Linux) code [here](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/ff2d8b19a3a62559afba1c53360c8577a7697714/include/linux/kernel.h#L57):

```
#define FIELD_SIZEOF(t, f) (sizeof(((t*)0)->f))
```

What does `((t*)0)->f)` do?

How does it work?

Comment: do you know http://cdecl.org ? (not a solution for this problem, though)

Comment: Do you know any C? Do you know what `->` does?

Comment: just lets `sizeof` to determine size of  the `f` field of a struct of type `t`.

Comment: An attempt to shoot himself in the foot?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does this implementation of offsetof() work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/713963/why-does-this-implementation-of-offsetof-work)

Comment: Note C call the `struct` parts "members", not "fields".

Comment: @chux, given the source of this example, it looks like Linus don't care.

Answer (score 4):

The thing does exactly what the name suggests – deliver the size of a field of a struct.

what it first does is cast 0 (which is an arbitrary address) to a pointer of the type of struct.

Then it `->` (access via pointer) takes the field and applies `sizeof` to it.

Pretty straightforward!

Comment: `0` is not arbitrary; it's a null pointer constant, so `(t*)0` is a null pointer.

Comment: It is worth noting that the `sizeof` operator does not evaluate the value it is used on, or else you'd get undefined behaviour. If it is UB even so is a matter of some debate...

Comment: @melpomeme. Giving the pointer a name does not make it any less arbitrary in this context. Any other value would have worked as well. Also, NULL is technically an implementation dependent value that is not required to be zero.

Comment: @MadPhysicist but casting the integer 0 to a pointer type is required to give the NULL pointer.

Comment: @Ajay. That is just not true in general: https://stackoverflow.com/q/2597142/2988730

Comment: @Ajay. Not to mention the fact that NULL is technically not any kind of pointer.

Comment: @MadPhysicist [C standard 6.3.2.3p3](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.2.3p3) I am not saying NULL pointer should have a value 0 (a pointer is not even required to be an integer), I am just saying casting 0 to a pointer type gives a NULL pointer constant.

Comment: @MadPhysicist in the link you pointed, look at this [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2597142/when-was-the-null-macro-not-0#comment2606463_2597232)

Answer (score 3):

It does what it says on the tin, like [Marcus Müller explains](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47116409/817643). If you are wondering why bother with it, why can't we just do `sizeof(type_of_field)` instead, then consider this:

```
struct foo {
  struct {
    int a;
    float b;
  } bar;
};
```

We cannot name `type_of_bar`, since for the programmer it has no name. But the macro allows us to obtain the field size via a workaround, regardless.

Answer (score 1):

Because sizeof is computed at compile time (except in the case of variable length arrays, which is not the case here) its argument is not evaluated at runtime. It is therefore OK to cast a NULL pointer, as it's only used to indicate the field for which size is being computed.

Comment: This is crucial information that is not mentioned enough.

Comment: The code actually has an assumption in it. It's not true in general.